# What GraphQL host name to use when developing locally with React-Native?

Tags: react-native, asp.net-web-api, graphql, localhost

I'm trying to fetch data using localhost api which created by **dotnet web API** and used in react native application I use axios and fetch method but I'm not getting data in graphQL I used my local system IP address , that not throwing error but no data comes from it and when I use localhost api of swagger which created from .NET CORE WEB API it is not working anyone have a idea how to call API successfully i also tried Android mobile IP address like 10.0.2.2 but it also not working.

I add IP address instead of localhost and Android IP address like 10.0.2.2 also but it is not working

[image: app.js]

[image: query.js]

[image: home.js]

and this is my app.js , query.js and homescreen.js in this code I'm getting result like only fetching data but not actual data but the query is working properly in graphql API.

Comment: In react-native I normally use the IP address of the localhost (the computer, not the phone) for my server.

Comment: yes i also use localhost of my computer but it also not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Now the problem is solved. You just need to run your web api project on http instead of https, and in your url, you need to replace localhost with an emulator IP address. In my case, I use the gateway IP of the emulator (ex. 10.0.2.2). and finally, it will work